# Angular2 - Why does this fail? Parser limitation?

Tags: angular

I have a feed that pulls in a list of objects, within this list there are various images:

[image]

**In my code I will grab the original image like this:**

```
<img src="{{MyObject.logo.original}}" >
```

However, if I try and grab any of the numeric names:

```
<img src="{{MyObject.logo.100X100}}" >
```

**I get the following error:**

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: Parser
>   Error: Unexpected token '0.5' at column 19 in
>   [{{MyObject.logo.50X50}}] in MyComponent@12:25 ("tArray"
>   class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
>                   
>                       ]src="{{MyObject.logo.50X50}}" >
>                       
>                    "): MyComponent@12:25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identifier starting with a digit is invalid. Use instead

```
{{MyObject.logo['50X50']}}
```

Comment: Any idea as to "why" it is invalid?